# How to cater for www condition in my htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the current rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /s/index.php?s=%1 [L]
```

Basically, what this does is that it points test.domain.com to www.domain.com/s/index.php?s=test .

The 2nd line of code is to prevent www.domain.com from pointing to /s/index.php ... (This is my main site)

However the above rules and code do not work for www.test.domain.com .

I want both test.domain.com and www.test.domain.com to point to www.domain.com/s/index.php?s=test.

Comment: What do you mean "point to both"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/s/index.php?s=%2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, may i know what isthe purpose of ^(www.)?

Comment: It checks for the existence of www at the beginning, consumes it if it exists and assigns the part after that to %1. The second condition then checks for your exception (www.domain.com).